# How to autoplay audio in HTML?

Tags: html

How to autoplay an audio in Chrome browser?
I found some similar question in here, but when i try the solution they gave, it didn't work for me.
Any new solution for this problem?

Comment: Please read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  Saying that _it didn't work_ or not including any code in your question does not really help anyone in troubleshooting what you tried.

Comment: @SaiManoj can't work in chrome. Chrome block the audio autoplay. Any tips?

Comment: You can’t. Autoplay is disabled purposefully for user experience. Most browsers require user interaction for sound. Also, don’t do it even if you can.

Answer (score -1):

To autoplay an audio file in the Chrome browser you can just add autoplay in the audio tag

Example:

```
<audio id="audio_id" autoplay>
  <source src="path/to/audiofile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code

Your browser does not support the audio element.

Comment: what code? there is no code in your answr